# One Cocoa app notified when another cocoa app terminated

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nsapplication, nsworkspace

Suppose there are two cocoa apps APP1 and APP2. I want APP2 to be notified when APP1 terminates. I want some callback function registered with APP2 which will be called as soon as APP1 terminates. How can I achieve this? Any sample code will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can observe the `NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification`. Its `userInfo` dictionary contains details about which application was terminated (an `NSRunningApplication` object).

Answer (score 0):

You certainly looking for [NSDistributedNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDistributedNotificationCenter).

Whenever you want to send a notification from One app to Other, just like XCode3.2 and Interface Builder were sending notifications, use **NSDistributedNotificationCenter**.

This documentation contains sample code such as DockTile, that will come handy to you.